# Matplotlib drawing excessive tick labels, drawing data incorrectly

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

So, I am building a tkinter GUI program which has a matplotlib graph on one of the pages. From various popups, the user can add, delete, and modify the traces on the graph.

What I had been doing up till now is using the `draw()` method on the `FigureCanvasTkAgg` object to update the graphic whenever something is changed. I have read in several other posts that this redraws the *entire* figure, and makes the rendering very slow. Additionally, in my specific case, it draws a *lot* of tick labels on the axes, seemingly one for every point in the source, so, in addition to taking forever, it also makes the graph absolutely unreadable. It also does not plot the data correctly.

I came across some posts suggesting not to use the draw method, as it redraws the entire figure, but that doesn't really explain why so many tick labels are being drawn, or why the data isn't being plotted as expected. I've looked into using animate, but I'm not sure that that's what I need, because the graph doesn't have to update constantly, only when it's changed by the user.

I'm using Python 3.7.2, and matplotlib 3.1.1. The data I'm plotting is spectral, and only has about 4000 points. I've also tested it with very small datasets (10-15 points) and this doesn't seem to happen. I've also tried setting the tick labels with `axis.locator_params(nbins=10)`, but it doesn't prevent all those labels from being drawn.

Any idea what's happening here, and how I can prevent it? Here's the graphic it produces, and the relevant parts of my code. Sorry if I'm missing anything; I'm new to SO and I'm still a relatively inexperienced programmer.

The offensive graph:
[image]

```
class App(tk.Tk): ###The controller of all pages, & control of operations
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        self.dfs = {}  #contains dataframes loaded from csv/made by the user
        self.spectra = {} #contains spectrum objects
        self.plots = {} #contains Figure objects. Each figure can have exactly one axis
        
        for F in (HomePage, SpectraPage, GraphPage, MakeSpectrumPage):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(HomePage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        self.frames[cont].tkraise()

    def load(self, filename):
        df = pd.read_csv(filename, header=None)
        if any(df.iloc[0].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, str))):
            df = df[1:].reset_index(drop=True).rename(columns=df.iloc[0])
        else:
            names=[]
            for i in range(len(df.columns)):
                names.append("w%i" %i)
            df.columns = names
        self.dfs[filename] = df
        self.frames[MakeSpectrumPage].makeFileList()
            
    def get_dfs(self):
        return self.dfs

    def get_spectra(self):
        return self.spectra

    def get_plots(self):
        return self.plots

    def make_spectrum(self, name, df, x, y):
        spectrum = Spectrum(name, df, x, y)
        self.spectra[name] = spectrum
        self.frames[SpectraPage].insertItems()

    def make_plot(self, name):
        fig = Figure(dpi=100)
        fig.suptitle(name)
        axis = fig.add_subplot(111, xlim=(4000, 500), ylim=(0,1))
        axis.locator_params(nbins=10)
        self.plots[name] = fig
        
    def graph(self, axis, spectrum, **kwargs): #plot spectrum obj
        axis.plot(spectrum.xdata, spectrum.ydata, label=spectrum.name, **kwargs)
```

```
class GraphPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller=controller
        
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        
        self.controller.make_plot('Plot 1')
        self.showFigure(self.controller.get_plots()['Plot 1'])
        self.makeGraphTray()

                
    def showFigure(self, fig):
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, self)
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.canvas._tkcanvas.grid(row=1, column=1, rowspan=2, columnspan=2)
        self.makeToolbar()

    def makeToolbar(self):
        self.toolbar_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.toolbar_frame.grid(row=3,column=1, columnspan=2)
        
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(self.canvas, self.toolbar_frame)
        self.toolbar.update()

    def makeGraphTray(self):
        #make container for graph/trace modification buttons
        self.graphTray = tk.Frame(self, width=50)
        self.graphTray.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky='nsew')

        addTraceButton = ttk.Button(self.graphTray, text="Add Trace", command=lambda:self.raisePopup(NewTracePopup))
        addTraceButton.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

    def raisePopup(self, Popup):
        popup = Popup(self)
```

```
class Spectrum: #Objects of this class are two-column structures.
    def __init__(self, name, sourcedf, x, y):
        self.xdata = sourcedf[x]
        self.ydata = sourcedf[y]
        self.df = pd.concat([self.xdata, self.ydata], axis=1)
        self.name = name
```

```
class ConditionalPopup(tk.Toplevel):
    #parent class of OK/Cancel popups where OK is disabled until all fields are filled
    def __init__(self, master, title, **kwargs):#@param **kwargs the Variables traced by the widgets in the popup

        if all(isinstance(kwarg, tk.Variable) for kwarg in kwargs.values()):
            super().__init__(master)
            self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
            self.master = master

            self.vars = kwargs #dictionary of kwargs
            
            self.wm_title(title)

            self.widgetFrame = tk.Frame(self)
            self.widgetFrame.grid(row=0, column=0)

            self.traceVars()
            self.makeWidgets(self.widgetFrame)
            self.placeWidgets()
            
        else: raise TypeError
       
    def traceVars(self):
        for var in self.vars.values():
            var.trace('w', self.activateOK)

    def activateOK(self, *args):
        if all(self.vars[key].get() for (key, value) in self.vars.items()):
            self.okButton.configure(state='normal')
        else:
            self.okButton.configure(state='disabled')

    def makeWidgets(self, frame):
        self.okButton = ttk.Button(self, text="OK", state='disabled', command=self.okPressed)
        self.cancelButton = ttk.Button(self, text="Cancel", command=self.destroy) 
        
    def placeWidgets(self):
        self.okButton.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=2.5, pady=10, sticky='e')
        self.cancelButton.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=2.5, pady=10, sticky='w')

    def okPressed(self, *args):
        self.destroy()
```

```
class NewTracePopup(ConditionalPopup):
    #a popup that enables adding a trace to a chosen plot
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master, "Add trace to plot",
                         plotVar=tk.StringVar(),
                         spectrumVar=tk.StringVar(),
                         colorVar=tk.StringVar(),
                         linewidthVar=tk.StringVar())


    def activateOK(self, *args):
        if self.linewidthVar.get().isdecimal():
            super().activateOK(*args)

    def makeWidgets(self, frame):
        self.plotLabel = tk.Label(frame, text="Plot:")
        self.plotCombobox = ttk.Combobox(frame, state='readonly', values=list(self.master.controller.get_plots().keys()), textvariable=self.plotVar)

        self.spectrumLabel = tk.Label(frame, text="Spectrum:")
        self.spectrumCombobox = ttk.Combobox(frame, state='readonly', values=list(self.master.controller.get_spectra().keys()), textvariable=self.spectrumVar)

        self.cLabel = tk.Label(frame, text="Colour:")
        self.cCombobox = ttk.Combobox(frame, state='readonly', values=list(mcolors.BASE_COLORS)+list(mcolors.TABLEAU_COLORS), textvariable=self.colorVar)

        self.mLabel = tk.Label(frame, text="Line width:")
        self.mEntry = ttk.Entry(frame, textvariable=self.linewidthVar)

        super().makeWidgets(frame)
        
    def placeWidgets(self):
        self.plotLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky='e')
        self.plotCombobox.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky='w')

        self.spectrumLabel.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky='e')
        self.spectrumCombobox.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky='w')

        self.cLabel.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky='e')
        self.cCombobox.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky='w')

        self.mLabel.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky='e')
        self.mEntry.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky='w')

        super().placeWidgets() 

    def okPressed(self, *args):
           self.master.controller.graph(self.master.controller.get_plots()[self.plotVar.get()].axes[0],
                                            self.master.controller.get_spectra()[self.spectrumVar.get()],
                                            color=self.colorVar.get(),
                                            linewidth=float(self.linewidthVar.get()))
            self.master.canvas.draw()
            super().okPressed()
```

Comment: Your data are strings.  Change your data to floats and the extra ticks will go away and be plotted in correct order

Comment: @JodyKlymak Of course, so obvious... Thank you!